# Can I achieve a 'copy constructor' in C# that copies from a derived class?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

An application specific example to illustrate my immediate problem:

I have a metadata provider class with the following (abridged) interface:

```
public class CtsDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
        return metadata;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to extend `ModelMetadata` with additional properties, populate these and return and instance of `ExtendedModelMetadata`. How can I nicely convey properties assigned to the `metadata` instance by `base.CreateMetadata` in my extended instance? What I would like but don't have is;

```
var metadata = (ExtendedModelMetadata)base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);
```

I can create a constructor for `ExtendedModelMetadata` that takes a `ModelMetadata` parameter and explicitly assigns all of it's properties to the instance being constructed, but I would like a more generic and less hard-coded approach for this. What can I do?

Comment: I know this post is quite old, but I was in a similar situation and found a solution to what you were trying to do, check the answer if you're curious: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627312/how-can-i-extend-dataannotationsmodelmetadata/16680163#16680163

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to achieve this.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ModelMetaData , ExtendedModelMetadata>();
```

.NET Framework does not provide a deep copy feature.

Comment: I am already using AutoMapper, and love it, but I would prefer something without a non-.NET dependency. I implemented a very neat and quick interim AutoMapper solution and may just stick with it though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection and generics (this is a cheap, home-grown example that copies all fields, it makes quite a few assumptions for the sake of brevity):

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Base b = new Base();
            b.Number = 42;

            Derived d = Copy<Derived, Base>(b);
            Console.Read();
        }

        static TDerived Copy<TDerived, TBase>(TBase b)
            where TDerived : TBase, new()
        {
            TDerived d = new TDerived();

            var bType = typeof(TBase);
            var bFields = bType.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            
            foreach (var field in bFields)
            {
                object val = field.GetValue(b);
                field.SetValue(d, val);
            }

            return d;
        }
    }

    class Base
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }

    class Derived : Base
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

This assumes that the type has a default parameterless constructor, but you get the idea.

Alternatively, if performance is an issue you could do something like create a code generator that code-gens the assignment code using partial classes.

Comment: That is what `AutoMapper` does.

Comment: @Aliostad Didn't know that, never used AutoMapper. I was coding this as you posted your answer. Personally for something this small I'd roll my own to avoid taking a dependency.

Comment: @Aliostad Well in this case I might just lift the code straight out of Auto Mapper if it isn't too dependent on other internal stuff. But I'd still avoid the dependency on an ORM framework for something as simple as copy constructors.

Comment: This will handle deeper dependencies, for example if you have nested class hierarchies... and it is small. But again everyone will make their own choice.

Comment: @Aliostad Yes I can imagine it works entirely, whereas my 5 minute example of what could potentially be done doesn't... lol

Comment: +1 for your time. I used AutoMapper as an interim solution, but given its apparent ubiquity, I think I'll keep it, but your input will come in handy elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would split out creation and population if possible.

```
public class CtsDataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var extended = new ExtendedModelMetadata();
        PopulateMetadata(extended, attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        return extended ;
    }

    protected override void PopulateMetadata(ModelMetaData data, IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
         base.PopulateMetaData(data, attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        //populate extended properties.
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that. I had already implemented this strategy with an *AutoMapper* based population method as an interim solution.